# TypeError: util.promisify is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise

I'm trying to promisify `zlib.gunzip` in my react application:

```
const zlib = require('zlib')
const util = require('util')

const gunzipPromisified = util.promisify(zlib.gunzip)
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: util.promisify is not a function

That works fine if I put it in a standalone script file and run it through `node`.

If I try:

```
import zlib from 'zlib'
import util from 'util'

const gunzipPromisified = util.promisify(zlib.gunzip)
```

I get something even fancier:

> TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8_util___default.a.promisify is not a function

What am I missing?

[Edit] The node.js version installed on my laptop is 8.9.1.

[Edit] As somebody commented, the node.js installed in my local development environment has nothing to do with what the app code has access to in the browser. So now my question is, how do I determine what API I have access to in the browser?

Comment: @JaromandaX the node.js installed is 8.9.1, but I also find that there is a `node_module/util` within my project, which is 0.10.3. Is that thing overriding the util module from the node.js installed?

Comment: @JaromandaX I see your point. I suspected as much, too. OTOH, `zlib`, also a node.js standard module, is apparently available to the application code. So I'm very confused too :-)

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @Ari yes, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course everything works fine when I switch to bluebird's `Promise`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Ionic. The util promisify didn't work for me either, and generated the same error as the one for OP. I ended up using [this simple solution](https://medium.com/@santypk4/promisify-any-function-7228353059ec) copied below:

```
const promisify = (fn) => {
 return (...args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      fn(...args, function(err, res){
        if(err){
          return reject(err);
        }
        return resolve(res);
      })
    })
  }
}
```

And then:

```
const requestPromisified = promisify(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it got fixed by updating Node to a version higher than Node 7.

```
n latest
```

In my case Node 9.2.0 as this was added later.

Comment: You are correct. As command "n" was not defined, I used the following command:  nvm use 8